# Multiple select to be selected select multiple tag from dynamic data query

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and I have a two-sided multi-select box. One side should display all rows which are not present in the second side and vice versa. I am using php mysql.

```
<select  name="job_rights[]" multiple="multiple" id="msc">
    <?php
    foreach ($all_active_locations as $value) {
      //$selected = in_array ($value["location_id"],$user_location_rights_selected["selected_loc_id"]) ? ' selected="selected" ' : ''; 

      echo '<option value="' . $value["location_id"] . '" selected( true, in_array($value["location_id"], $user_location_rights_selected["selected_loc_id"]) );>'
        . $value["location_id"] .'/'. $value["location_name"] .  '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What errors are you getting? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: i added a multiple select list two sided. one side will load complete list of books except selected. other side loaded the list of books what i selected. for this i have two tables. one is master list of books. and second table has user name and book id and name which i selected. hope it is clear to support

Comment: pls help.. i want to compare two arrays. the matched array values as selected in the select box.